# do.call-like function for binary operators in R

Tags: r

Is there a built-in function in R for calling binary operators/functions over a list or data frame?

Take, for example, a data frame with three logicals:

```
set.seed(10)
foo <- matrix(as.logical(round(runif(24))), ncol = 3)
foo <- as.data.frame(foo)
```

Now I would like to do something like this:

```
do.call.bin("|", foo)
```

so that it applies the or-operator to all columns, yielding:

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

A possible implementation could be:

```
do.call.bin <- function (fun.bin, lst) {
    fun.bin <- match.fun(fun.bin)
    if (length(lst) > 2) {
        ret <- fun.bin(lst[[1]], Recall(fun.bin, lst[-1]))
    } else {
        ret <- fun.bin(lst[[1]], lst[[2]])
    }
    return (ret)
}
```

However, I doubt this isn't already implemented in R, though I haven't found it so far. Is there otherwise a more efficient way to do this?

I can't use `do.call()` since binary operators take only two arguments and I would like to apply a binary operator to more arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this case in particular, this would do the same trick:

```
> apply(foo, 1, function(x) Reduce("|", x))
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

I'm not sure if this will generalize to whatever real problem you have in mind, but it feels like something related to `Reduce` is what you have in mind, no?

Comment: Thanks, `Reduce` was exactly what I was looking for! `Reduce("|", foo)` does the job.

Answer (score 5):

You could try a different approach.  To perform column-wise operations, you can look at `apply(yourDF, 2, theFunction)`.  To apply the `|` operation on the whole vector, the `theFunction` can be `any`, e.g. `apply(foo, 2, any)`.

Given your example, though, I think you may be referring to row-wise operations, in which case the command would be `apply(foo, 1, any)`.

To get the equivalent of a vector-wise `&`, you can use `all` instead of `any`.

The nice aspect of these two are that they reportedly stop as soon as the result is determined, e.g. after the first `TRUE` for `any` and the first `FALSE` for `all`.